# Pearson residuals formula in a multinomial logit model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multinomial-distribution, residuals

Could someone tell me what's the formula for the Pearson residuals in a multinomial logit model?

I tried to look for it but I haven't found anything.

Comment: As far as I know "Poisson residuals" refers to residuals from a Poisson regression, not a multinomial logistic regression. Do you perhaps mean some other kind of residual? 

(Also, welcome to the site; I removed your signature since the site adds it automatically).

Comment: Hey, thank you.
Too much study is driving me crazy, i realized i did that mistake few minutes after asking the question.
I was actually referring to the Pearson residuals: the formula on my professor's note is different from those of the other GLM models (Gamma, Poisson, binomial logit) so i would like to see if there's a mistake on his notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat it like a log-linear model: for response categories $i$ and covariate patterns $j$, the Pearson residual is given by
$$\newcommand{\var}{\mathop{\mathrm{Var}}}
r_{ij} = \frac{y_{ij} - \hat{\mu}_{ij}}{\sqrt{\widehat{\var Y_{ij}}}}
=\frac{y_{ij} - \hat{\mu}_{ij}}{\sqrt{\hat{\mu}_{ij}}}$$,
where $y_{ij}$ is the observed count and $\hat{\mu}_{ij}$ the expected count according to your fitted model.

Comment: Where did you get the estimate of the variance of Y?
As far as i know, it should be something like n*p*(1-p), but in your formula it is something like n*p

Comment: Basically you can treat counts in contingency tables as Poisson variates (see any text on GLMs). If you're thinking of comparing binomial samples you can either calculate residuals like this for $2j$ cells (the log-linear model), or using the variance $n_jp_j(1-p_j)$ for $j$ observations (the logit model). The overall Pearsons's chi-square statistic will be the same.

Comment: Well i am interested merely on the single residual, not on the chi-square statistic.
What happens if i change the denominator of your first formula using the variance nj*pj*(1-pj)?
Will it still be correct and, if it isn't, why?